# Geometric series with even and odd coefficient

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, geometric-series

I have to determine the limit of a following geometric series:

$$t_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{2^k} $$ in which $$a_k=\begin{cases} 3 & \text{if $k$ is even}\\[2ex]
4 & \text{if $k$ is odd} \end{cases} $$

I'm not actually sure how should I approach this particular problem. 
Shall I examine the two cases separately and determine the limit for both cases respectively? Or is there some kind of trick to tackle this kind of a geometric series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{3}{2^{2j}}=4,\qquad \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{4}{2^{2j+1}}=\frac{8}{3}$$
(both are geometric series) hence:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{a_k}{2^k} = \color{red}{\frac{20}{3}}.$$
The rearrangement/splitting is allowed since we are clearly dealing with an absolutely convergent series.

Comment: Before we can rearrange the order of summation, I guess it would be prudent to verify that the series converges.  But since all terms are $\leq \frac{4}{2^k}$, this is not hard to show. (thanks for updating!)

Answer (score 1):

$$t_n=\begin{cases} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{3}{2^k} & \text{if $k$ is even}\\[2ex]
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{4}{2^k} & \text{if $k$ is odd} \end{cases} $$

Consider the two subsequences $t_{2n}$ and $t_{2n-1}$ where 
$t_{2n}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{3}{2^k}$ 
 and $t_{2n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{4}{2^k}$

Now these subsequences include all terms of the main series and they are both monotonic decreasing and bounded below.

If they converge to same limit, they converge. Else, they do not.

Now do the subsequences have the same limit? Check it.

Comment: FYou seem to be saying that each even-indexed partial sum is the sum of the even-indexed terms.  But that's not true.  Your cases definition of $t_n$ splits on a dummy variable, not on $n$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang No,no you got me wrong. That's never true. I am updating my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: You say $t_{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{3}{2^k}$, which would mean $t_4 = \frac{3}{1} + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{8}+ \frac{3}{16}$.  But $t_4 = \frac{3}{1} + \frac{\color{red}{4}}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{\color{red}{4}}{8} + \frac{3}{16}$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Give me a few minutes. I noticed what actually caused the confusion.

Comment: I determined the limit for the both series.  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{3}{2^k}=6$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{4}{2^k}=8$ They don't have the same limit. Does it mean this function has no limit?

Answer (score 0):

$t_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{2^k}=3(\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot)+4(\frac12+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdot\cdot\cdot)=(3+\frac42)(\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot)=5(\frac{1}{1-\frac14})$

Thus $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{2^k}=\frac{20}{3}$$